# in Android how to overlay image in VideoView?

Tags: android

I need to show images one after another over VideoView, the problem that i am getting is that whenever the image is displayed the area means(layout) where the imageview is placed   becomes white. So as a result a white mark comes over the video.
      So how can I fix it.
Thanks.

Comment: i think you need to develop app in which sliding of images are stay there. so user can see slide of image one by one.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial might help you: [Getting your Images laid (pause) over a video in android](http://littlesaiph.blogspot.com/2011/07/getting-images-laid-pause-over-video-in.html)